# Return a list of the values of a column of pandas dataset

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas dataset and I want to have a list with the values of a column, without repetitions. For example if you have the following dataset

```
import pandas as pd
ds = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 'col2':[2021, 2022, 2022, 2021]})
```

you should have, for the column `col2`, the following return `[2021, 2022]`. I'm using this command:

```
ds['col2'].value_counts().index.to_list()
```

It's working and its output is `[2021, 2022]`. Does a better command exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `unique()` to get the unique values and then cast this to a list.

so this works:

```py
import pandas as pd
ds = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 'col2':[2021, 2022, 2022, 2021]})

ds['col2'].unique().tolist()
```

returns this:

```
[2021, 2022]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
set(ds['col2'])
```

Granted, that is not a list, but since you want unique values, a `set` might be the better data type. You can always convert it to a list with an extra step: `list(set(ds['col2']))`.

Note that a set does not preserve the order of the elements: `set[2, 1]` is equivalent to `set[1, 2]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

ds = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 'col2':[2021, 2022, 2022, 2021]})

print(list(dict.fromkeys(ds['col2']))) # The fromkeys() method returns a dictionary with the specified keys. The list() function creates a list object.
```

Comment: Why do you use dictionary, set looks more appropriate here.

Comment: @DonchoGunchev "and I want to have a **list** with the values of a column, without repetitions"

Comment: `dict.fromkeys(ds['col2'])` == `{2021: None, 2022: None}`, set removes repetition, the dictionary contains only `None` as values. The `print(list(set(ds['col2'])))` does output the same thing, 1:1. Dict preserves order of keys though, set does not (python 3.x+).